# Proof Verification: Baby Rudin Chapter 1 Exercise 6(d)

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I am tring to get through Exercise 6(d) of Chapter 1, Principle of Mathematical Analysis, 3rd. by Rudin.

> 6. Fix $b > 1 $.
>    (a) If $m, n, p, q$ are integers, $n>0$, $q>0$, and $r=m/n=p/q$ prove that $ (b^m)^{\frac{1}{n}}=(b^p)^{\frac{1}{q}}$
>    (b) Prove that $b^{r+s}=b^rb^s$ if $r$ and $s$ are rational.
>    (b) If $x$ is real, define $B(x)$ to be the set of all numbers $b^t$, where $t$ is rational and $t\leq x$. Prove that $$b^r=\text{sup}B(r)$$ when $r$ is rational.
>    (d) Prove that $b^{x+y} = b^xb^y$ for all real $x$ and $y$.

My approach to prove the proposition in (d) is by proving the below target proposition
$$ \text{(*)   }\text{sup}B(x+y) = \text{sup}B(x)\text{sup}B(y).$$

(*) could be divided by two component propositions.

> (1) $\text{sup}B(x)\text{sup}B(y)$ is an upper bound of $\text{sup}B(x+y)$. 
> (2) $\text{sup}B(x)\text{sup}B(x)\text{ is the "least" upper bound of }\text{sup}B(x+y).$

And I proceeded to prove that $\text{sup}B(x)\text{sup}B(y)$ is an upper bound of $\text{sup}B(x+y)$, under the lemma $$\text{sup}B(x) = \text{sup}B'(x)\text{ for }B'(x) = \{b^t: t\in \mathbb{Q}, t < x\}$$

What I want to be verified is the proof of $$ \text{sup}B(x)\text{sup}B(x)\text{ is the "least" upper bound of }\text{sup}B(x+y).$$

Below is how I attempted to prove.

Suppose there exists $\alpha$ such that $0<\alpha<\text{sup}B(x)\text{sup}B(y)$. Then there exists $\alpha_1 > 0, \alpha_2 > 0$ such that $\alpha = \alpha_1 \alpha_2$ and $\alpha_1 < \text{sup}B(x)$ and $\alpha_2 < \text{sup}B(y)$. Let $\alpha_1 =\text{sup}B(x) / (\frac{\text{sup}B(x)\text{sup}B(y)}{\alpha})^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and $\alpha_2 =\text{sup}B(y) / (\frac{\text{sup}B(x)\text{sup}B(y)}{\alpha})^{\frac{1}{2}}$. Then $\alpha_1 < \text{sup}B(x)$ since $(\frac{\text{sup}B(x)\text{sup}B(y)}{\alpha})^{\frac{1}{2}} > 1$. Similarly $\alpha_2 < \text{sup}B(y)$.

Now it is easy to observe that there exist rational $t, s$ such that $b^t \in B(x)$ and $b^x \in B(y)$ and $\alpha_1<b^t<\text{sup}B(x)$, $\alpha_2<b^s<\text{sup}B(y)$. Then

$$ \alpha = \alpha_1\alpha_2 < b^tb^s = b^{t+s}\leq \text{sup}B(x)\text{sup}B(y)$$
and $b^{t+s} \in B(x+y)$.

I think the above discussion is sufficient to prove $$ \text{sup}B(x)\text{sup}B(x)\text{ is the "least" upper bound of }\text{sup}B(x+y).$$

Thank you.